# django framework 404 error page not found

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I'm getting this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in sitaram.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

members/ [name='members']
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: First, you need to format your question. Add an image of the page you are seeing at 404 error and DEBUG=True. However, I think you need to add a handler404 in urls.py and a dedicated view for that in views.py if you want to load your page when debug = True. refer: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_404.php

Answer (score -1):

Well the error is quite clear, you try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, but there is no `path` in your `urls.py` that matches this. You can visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/members/`, or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` given these point to views and are not just includes, but you can not point to the root directly, since you did not define such path.